# How to handle a modified link click event in a Firefox extension?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, mozilla

When you click a link the linked page is opened in the current tab. If you click a link while holding a `Ctrl` button pressed the linked page is opened in a new background tab. I want to implement an extension that would capture Alt+Clicks or Shift+Clicks so when a user clicks a link while holding an `Alt` button pressed a function of mine gets the link target URL (and nothing else but what I have programmed happens). How can this be achieved? An SDK way is very much preferred.

Answer (score 1):

Do this, can be done from sdk content script or bootstrap addon or overlay addon. if do from bootstrap/overlay then instead of adding to every document, then just add once to the gBrowser so instead of document.addEv... do gBrowser.addEventL...

```
document.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
    if (e.altKey && e.ctrlKey && e.button = 0 && e.target.nodeName == 'a') {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        //do what you want, you may have to atach a mouseup preventer liek this
        document.addEventListener('mouseup', function(e) {
            document.removeEventListener('mouseup', arguments.callee, false);
            e.preventDefault);
            e.stopPropagation();
        }. false);
    }
});
```